# GAE datastore put and get

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Hi I'm just playing around with the datastore and hoping someone can tell my why my simple code doesn't work? I have just been playing around with how to put and get strings from the datastore...  unfortunately my GAE ability is weak alongside my weak java ability...

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoopingProgramServlet extends HttpServlet {
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws IOException {


    Key key = KeyFactory.createKey("a","b");        
    String Teststring = "pleasework";
    Entity greeting = new Entity("meh", key);
    greeting.setProperty("teststring", Teststring);     
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    datastore.put(greeting);



    Entity greetings = null;
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    resp.getWriter().println("doing something");


    try {
        greetings = datastore.get(key);
        String string = (String) greetings.getProperty("teststring");


        if (string == null) {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("null");   
            System.out.println("null");
        } else {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("contains something"); 
            System.out.println("contains something");
        }

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println(string);   

    } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Entity` construct that you're using is interpreting the `Key` argument as the key to a parent entity. Since no id or keyName are given (as would happen if you instead used one of the other `Entity` constructors described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Entity#constructor_summary)), an id will be generated for the greeting at `put` time.

`datastore.get(key)` is returning null because `key` refers to an entity of kind "a" with a keyName of "b", which (I'm guessing) doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you so much. It was the simplest fix in the world and now it all makes so much sense... I apologise for being retarded I was merely trying to follow tutorials that weren't quite specific to how I wanted it to work!

Comment: No problem. The first time through, it's easy to miss the significance of some things that'll make more sense later.